# Video Streaming through Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video-streaming, chat

I am using XMPP framework for chat in my app. now i want to implement video chat in this app.

i heard about Jingle. is there any sample code for that?

Comment: me too still finding this....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the source code here :

[Two-way Video Conferencing for iPhone](http://www.theiphonedev.com/SourceCode/CodeSearch/tabid/144/agentType/View/PropertyID/47/Default.aspx)

But bare in mind that those who have made video chat work for iphone keep their source codes close to themselves (google, oovoo, ect.)